# App Engine Task Queues targeted to a backend instance fail to run

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Our App Engine application uses task queues targeted to a backend instance for certain critical tasks. On Friday, 28th of July, 2016 at approximately 8 PM IST, there were tasks clogged up inside the task queue.

There were 8 tasks inside the queue. The targeted backend is a dynamic backend that could spawn up to 4 instances. Upon inspecting the the retry logs for the tasks from the dashboard, the clog was due to a 404(Instance Not Available) error. There were no executions for the tasks.

Restarting the backend did resume their execution. This is the third instance of such a problem. The Google Cloud Status page does not show any outages or service disruption for Appengine either.

Comment: 404 means the handler not available, not the instance. What do you mean by dynamic backend? What scaling setting do you use for the target the backend?

Comment: @marcadian The <dynamic> tag in backends.xml is set to true for the targeted backend. What does handler being unavailable mean?

Comment: maybe your backend module does not know how to handle the url request

Comment: Not using the modules API either. The backends are deployed with the same codebase, so the handler not being found isn't possible either. It should consistently fail that way, and not go ahead after a backend restart.